# Unix magic, delete all .pyc files from a tree of directories?

Tags: unix, find, rm

Is there a quick way of deleting all the .pyc files from a tree of directories?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you've got GNU find then you probably want

```
find <directory name> -name '*.pyc' -delete
```

If you need something portable then you're better off with

```
find <directory name> -name '*.pyc' -exec rm {} \;
```

If speed is a big deal *and* you've got GNU find and GNU xargs then

```
find <directory name> -name '*.pyc' -print0|xargs -0 -p <some number greater than 1> rm
```

This is unlikely to give you that much of a speed up however, due to the fact that you'll mostly be waiting on I/O.

Comment: Just in case I have files with spaces in the names, I've gotten into the habit of always using -print0 and "xargs -0".

Comment: You're entirely right, should have thought of that originally., edited to reflect that.

Comment: You can also directly use '-delete' instead of '-print0 | xargs -0 rm'. But that's true that this option isn't present in all version of 'find'.

Answer (score 6):

using the command find:

```
find /path/to/start -name '*.pyc' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Comment: That's too slow. Using xargs is faster, or if your version of find supports it, change the "`\;`" at the end to a "`+`".

Comment: It may be a little slower--it runs "rm" once for each file instead of batching them--but it's the most portable way to do it. The OP didn't say what kind of unix he was using, and Solaris find still doesn't have the -print0 feature.

Comment: +1, OP said unix not linux, this is the best portable solution.

Comment: I think this solution is the only permitting to remove tons of files, if I am not wrong using xargs can leave into a command line too long error. +1, it is my choice since years too.

Comment: If you are using a makefile to build your project, you might want to add this in to the target "clean".

Answer (score 1):

cd to the start of the tree of directories then:

find . -name '*.pyc' |xargs rm -f

Comment: It's not necessary to `cd`, just put the top directory in the `find` command (in place of "dot").

Comment: This doesn't handle spaces at all.